# Error when i am trying to install NPM in any laravel application

Tags: laravel, npm, laravel-5.4

Before, when i installed `NPM` in any `laravel` project there was no problem. 
But, suddenly now when i am trying to install `npm`, I am getting the below error:

[image]

Comment: This is not imgur.  Please post the *text* of your errors, so future users searching for that error will be able to find it.

Comment: cjpeg cannot be opened because of a problem.
Check with the developer to make sure cjpeg works with this version of macOS. You may need to reinstall the application. Be sure to install any available updates for the application and macOS.

Click Report to see more detailed information and send a report to Apple.